# Setting cookie when an Ajax requested is returned from a different domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, basic-authentication

I have a mobile web app which requires basic authentication. I managed to invoke a basic authentication with Ajax on a server that is of different domain. However, I have a problem with the response.

Normally, a session id would be set in the browser by the Ajax response through the set cookie header. I noticed that this didn't happen upon successful authentication.

What I did was to try to set the cookie manually by reading the headers when the response is returned. I achieved this via jQuerys jqxhr object. To my surprise even though the server indicated that a sessionID was returned, I was unable to see any set cookie header in the response through jqxhr.

Is this the expected behavior of a cross domain request? That some response headers would get dropped? Is this a security feature of the browser? If so, what would you suggest to work around this (eg. Return the session id in the body, which I don't want to because I'm using Shiro security filter in the backed to take care of this, I don't want to need to hack it)?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ajax to request cross-domain uri. You'll have to implement your own server-side proxy, which will handle request/response with the distant authentification server. It could just copy/paste the response, but it has to be in the same domain as your client.

Same thing for cookies, they have a domain in which they can be read/written.

You'll be authorized to only request this proxy. It can also handle the cookie creation process, and then return the cookie id to the client.

For (a very simple) example, on www.auth.com, you have this webservice :

```
url : www.auth.com/auth
@params : string uuid, string password
@returns : int shiroSessionId // yes it's more complicated, but KISS for the example
```

You should create, on www.mydomain.com/myAuth a class which wget the www.auth.com/auth service with the same parameters and create local session cookie

```
url : /myAuth
@params : string uuid, string password
@returns : int cookieId, -1 if login failed
```

And finally in www.mydomain.com/login.html, you will have the following js call (here in jquery) :

```
$.ajax(function() {
  url : '/myAuth',
  date : {uuid: inputUuid, password: inputPassword}, // provided by a form
  success(cookieId) {
    if(cookieId > 0) {
      alert('logged with cookie '+getCookie(cookieId));
    } else {
      alert('login failed');
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: I'm using the Allow-Origin header on the server side, to allow a cross domain ajax request from my application. The application will be packaged with phone gap and deployed onto the mobile. So there won't be any server serving the application, it's just going to be running on the mobile. Since PhoneGap just packages it to run in a browser wrapper, the cross domain will probably still apply

Comment: As long as your header Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not "*", this works too.